# Bokeh 3.1.1 DeserializationError when changing layout content

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a project that worked fine under Bokeh 2.4.3 but after me upgrading to 3.1.1 produces `bokeh.core.serialization.DeserializationError`s.

The culprit is me having frames which first display a "loading screen" and afterwards an actual plot.
I have a class that manages a frame and looks somewhat like this, simplified:

```
class MyFrame:

    def __init__(self):
        self.layout = column()
        self.loading = loading_pic()
        self.layout.children.append(self.loading)

    def display_loading(self) -> None:
        self.layout.children[0] = self.loading

    def plot(self, data) -> None:
        self.my_plot = MyPlot(data)
        self.layout.children[0] = self.my_plot
```

In this, the function `loading_pic()` simply generates a (Bokeh) plot that contains the label "Loading", while the `MyPlot` class does some more sophisticated rendering.

This produces the error

```
2023-06-19 13:29:44,116 error handling message
 message: Message 'PATCH-DOC' content: {'events': [{'kind': 'ModelChanged', 'model': {'id': 'p1004'}, 'attr': 'inner_width', 'new': 865}, {'kind': 'ModelChanged', 'model': {'id': 'p1004'}, 'attr': 'inner_height', 'new': 540}, {'kind': 'ModelChanged', 'model': {'id': 'p1004'}, 'attr': 'outer_width', 'new': 900}, {'kind': 'ModelChanged', 'model': {'id': 'p1004'}, 'attr': 'outer_height', 'new': 550}]}
 error: DeserializationError("can't resolve reference 'p1004'")
```

Reference p1004 is the loading screen, and if I turn the code of `display_loading` into a comment, the error goes away (but of course so does the loading screen functionality).
Interestingly by my code as is, the loading screen plot object exists during the error, and also the loading screen is still actually used in the `__init__` method. And I actually see the loading screen during the initial loadup.

Now the error does not crash the program and it actually works despite it, but leaving it as is, suppressing it, or not using loading screens all feel like code smell to me.

Does anybody have an idea what causes this? Is Bokeh trying to resize an item that is not visible?

---

Edit: Also posted this issue in the Bokeh forums: https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/bug-with-deserializationerror-when-changing-content-layout-in-bokeh-3-1-1/10566

Edit: I created a whole reproducible example.
To reproduce the bug, execute the following code as Bokeh server and then change the value of the range slider *twice*.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Label, RangeSlider
from bokeh.layouts import column
from random import *

def loading_pic(width: int = 500, height: int = 500) -> figure:
    plot = figure(x_range=(0,width), y_range=(0,height), width=width, height=height, tools='')
    pos_x = width/2 
    pos_y = height/2    
    
    label_size = min(height/4, width/4)
    label_size_str = str(label_size)+'px'
    
    loading_label = Label(x=pos_x, y=pos_y, text='Loading', text_font_size = label_size_str,
                          text_align='center', text_baseline='middle')
    plot.add_layout(loading_label)
    
    plot.xaxis.visible = False
    plot.yaxis.visible = False
    plot.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
    plot.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
    
    return plot
    
def random_coords(maximum: float = 500, amount: int = 1000) -> ColumnDataSource:
    data = ColumnDataSource()
    data.data['x'] = [random()*maximum for i in range(amount)]
    data.data['y'] = [random()*maximum for i in range(amount)]
    return data
    
class MyPlot:
    
    def __init__(self, data: ColumnDataSource):
        self.plot = figure(x_range=(0,500), y_range=(0,500), width=500, height=500)
        self.plot.circle(source=data, x='x', y='y')
    
class MyFrame:

    def __init__(self):
        self.layout = column()
        self.loading = loading_pic()
        self.layout.children.append(self.loading)

    def display_loading(self) -> None:
        self.layout.children[0] = self.loading

    def plot(self, data) -> None:
        self.my_plot = MyPlot(data)
        self.layout.children[0] = self.my_plot.plot
        
    def plot_delayed(self, attr, old, new) -> None:
        self.display_loading()
        data = random_coords()
        curdoc().add_next_tick_callback(lambda: self.plot(data)) 
        
my_frame = MyFrame()
        
range_slider = RangeSlider(start = 0, end = 10, value = (0,10), step = 1, title = 'Range')
range_slider.on_change('value_throttled', my_frame.plot_delayed)
       
layout = column(my_frame.layout, range_slider)

curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the conversation I had about this in the Bokeh forums, this is potentially a bug within the library. Following the advice given there, I opened an issue in the Bokeh github:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/13229

Given that I'm not certain that this is indeed a library bug, I will keep this question open, without accepting my own answer for now.

---

Edit: Further Information: in Bokeh 3.2, this becomes a mere warning which describes itself as mostly harmless and is less verbose (does not show the stack trace anymore).
A maintainer proposed to change this into an information instead of a warning in an upcoming version.